# cv::Mat use row data to fill a new Mats columns

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I have a function which returns an opencv Mat, with 4 rows and 1 column. It runs in a for loop, iterating between two and 100 times.

What I need, is to copy the returned column to a new Mat, so that each iteration adds a new column.

I have (pseudo):

```
cv::Mat ResultMat(4, 1, CV_64F);

Mat returnMat(4, 1, CV_64F);

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {

returnMat= (function that returns a 4x1 Mat);

returnMat.col(0).copyTo(ResultMat.col(0));
   }
```

which works fine, but overwrites the Resultmat column each time.

Replacing the last line with

```
returnMat.col(0).copyTo(ResultMat.col(i));
```

causes an exception error.

EDIT: If I create the ResultMat as 'Resultmat(4, 100, CV_64F)', it works, but I need it to self-adjust the number of columns...

How can I add columns to the ResultMat dynamically, one for each loop?

Comment: do not use `return` as a variable name!

Comment: sorry that is just pseudo code! I will change it, for clarity.

Comment: [hconcat](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaf9771c991763233866bf76b5b5d1776f) for the dynamic approach

Comment: @Ben aren't the number of iterations equal to the number of columns you need for ResultMat?

Comment: Hi, the iterations will change number. I really would like the columns in the resulting mat to reflect the number. Thanks!

Comment: your answer is perfect. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why it didn't work for you when you changed the size of ResultMat. But here's a solution, given that you know the number of iterations, which is bascially the number of columns in the end result.
I defined a function func() to demonstrate the function called inside the loop.

```
Mat func() {

    Mat m(4, 1, CV_64F);
    randn(m, 0., 1.); // fill with random values.

    return m;
}

int main() {
    int iterations = 3;
    cv::Mat result(4, iterations, CV_64F);

    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {

        Mat m = func();
        m.col(0).copyTo(result.col(i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the no. of iterations is different from the no. of columns expected for ResultMat, I'd suggest to go with berak's suggestion to use hconcat or push_back and then transpose (not pretty for very big matrices). See berak's comment below the question.

Comment: This will work, as above. cv::Mat result(4, iterations, CV_64F);

I should have thought of that! many thanks.

Comment: You can also use `cv::Mat::push_back(...)` that is adding a row at the end and after finishing adding rows, transpose it (with `cv::Mat::t()`) to have the needed form